# Powershell CSV columns

Tags: powershell, csv, formatting

The script reports on VDHX size and filesize and adds a date to the end of the output. I plan to run this daily to get an idea of how much user profile disks space is being used up.

```cs
$lc   = "\\V22XX003\User Profile Disks\"
$ddr  = Get-ChildItem "$lc*.vhdx"
$time = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
$vhd  = Get-Vhd -Path $ddr | Select Path, Size, Filesize
$vhd | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value "$time"
}
$vhd | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path \\Besson\c$\udpsz\sizes.csv -Append
```

This gives me an output like this:

```
"Path","Size","FileSize","Date"
"\\V22XX003\User Profile Disks\UVHD-S-1-5-21-242017650-1976910495-1888779859-1168.vhdx","5368709120","2218786816","12-10-2017"
"\\V22XX003\User Profile Disks\UVHD-S-1-5-21-242017650-1976910495-1888779859-1169.vhdx","5368709120","2386558976","12-10-2017"
"\\V22XX003\User Profile Disks\UVHD-S-1-5-21-242017650-1976910495-1888779859-1174.vhdx","5368709120","2285895680","12-10-2017"
```

The problem I am facing is that the VHDX names may be added or removed so unable to hard code them in and I would like to be able to transpose the data so that the columns are the Path.

[image: Desired output]

Please let me know if I am barking mad or up a tree... :)

*** Here is the code I ended up with, it will write one file per VDHX and report on size max size and date per line ready for import into excel.
 I hope it helps a noobie like me some day :)

```
$csvout = "C:\testing\out\" #Path to the location you would like to write the report
$time = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); #Change the format of the date here
$vhdstore = "C:\testing\vhdx\" #where the VHDX are stored
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$vhdstore*.vhdx" #path to the VDHX files you want
$Files | ForEach-Object {
$FileFullName = $_.Name #in all honestesty I ripped this line from another script.
$TempFileName = "$csvout$FileFullName.csv"
$vhd = Get-Vhd -Path "$vhdstore$FileFullName" | Select Size,Filesize #get the properties we want in the output
add-member -inputObject $vhd -membertype noteproperty -name Date -value $time #Adding the date to the object
if (-Not (Test-Path $TempFilename)) { #this is just to check if the csv file is already created, if not make new file
$vhd | Export-Csv -Path $TempFileName -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","
}
```

Comment: A single CSV is not a good format for this kind of data. If you want to stick with CSV I'd create one CSV per disk.

Comment: I had wondered on this route but my colleague who is better than I at scripting said i should be able to to it in the mentioned manner.

Comment: So are you looking for a way to consolidate names of all the VHDX files dynamically?

Comment: Just because something is doable doesn't mean it's a good idea to actually do it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You want to change the nice looking horizontal csv format to the weird looking screenshot where you put things vertically? Man that is like Ansgar said, a really terrible way to show things. How many columns would be there? On an average, say 10 users on 30 servers would be 300 columns

Comment: I agree with the others, you need to rework your desired output concept because: There is no header above the date and there is only a single item (will there be date columns for every VHDX as well?, shouldn't the date be included in the related column? Or actually set as the header name (and the VHDX name as a field)? You currently have two columns with the same name, that is not a good idea if you work with this purposed table, besides in PowerShell this will need special treatment as you usually would be build a CSVfile from a list of objects that can't have the same property (column)names.

Comment: ...or (let your collegae) add the this record: `"\\V22XX003\User Profile Disks\UVHD-S-1-5-21-242017650-1976910495-1888779859-1234.vhdx","1234567890","0987654321","07-10-2017"` *(where every field is different, including the `date` field -which might grow indefinitely- and the `Path` -which will be likely very large-)* to the table concept for better understanding (or to realize that the table concept is really bad).

Comment: Ok, Many thanks guys / Gals !!!

I will probably go down the route of a separate file per VHDX, you have all been super, I like this site !! 
Also correcting my initially horrific post, I tried to do it to the best of my abilities and you sweep in and make everything better.

Comment: So I ended up using individual CSV's to do this.
I have added the code to the original question for future reference.

Does anybody know how I can thank the commentators above ??

Comment: Sorry for all the edits, turned out it needed tweaking.....